# Reusing a set of arguments in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I've got a set of common filters that are arguments on a range of different types to my graphQL api.

I would like to be able to declare the arguments and their types once and reuse this logic rather than adding it to every query.

Just wondering what is the best way to achieve this? Does the graphql spec cater for this use case or could I just declare the parameter set as a string and add it to the queries? Something like:

`let filterArgs = "timeStart: $startTime, timeEnd:$endTime, someFilter: $someFilter"`
`let filterTypes = "$startTime, DateTime!, $endTime: DateTime, $someFilter: String!"`

```
const SOME_QUERY = gql`
  query someQuery(${filterTypes}, $specificType: Int!) {
    someFilterableType(${filterArgs}) {
      someField
    }
    anotherFilterableType(${filterArgs}, additionalArg: $specificType)
  }
`;
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not really much else you can do client-side. This is really more of an issue with schema design. It often makes sense to convert multiple arguments on a field into a single input object type. It makes even more sense when those same arguments are duplicated across multiple fields in your schema. Compare

```
type Query {
  foo(baz: String, qux: String, quuz: String, corge: String, grault: String, garply: String, waldo: String, fred: String, plugh: String, xyzzy: String): Int!
  bar(baz: String, qux: String, quuz: String, corge: String, grault: String, garply: String, waldo: String, fred: String, plugh: String, xyzzy: String): Int!
}
```

with

```
type Query {
  foo(input: FilterInput): Int!
  bar(input: FilterInput): Int!
}

input FilterInput {
  baz: String
  qux: String
  quuz: String
  corge: String
  grault: String
  garply: String
  waldo: String
  fred: String
  plugh: String
  xyzzy: String
}
```

Reducing all those common arguments into an individual type not only reduces duplication in your schema but also simplifies the client's query:

```
query SomeQuery($input: FilterInput) {
  foo(input: $input)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! helped improve my understanding of GraphQL!